# To disable Clear button while all input fields are null

Tags: javascript

In the form that I am developing, I need to implement a screen rule which is - Clear button is greyed out until atleast one input field is not null. For this, I have added a js function which checks all input fields and gets called during "onmousemove" event. I have added this to body tag. 
I does work, but I suspect if this is the best way it can be done. 
Are there better ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a good idea to bind to `onmousemove`, especially on `body` — that means every time someone moves their mouse, your function is called. What you really want is to bind to `blur` (navigates away from an input field) or `change` (the value of a field is changed – be careful with IE). If you really want to get granular, you can check one of the keyboard events — `keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress`. And you should bind these events to the *input fields* themselves.

Comment: ,Purmou  Thanks for the answers. I did add it to all fields at first, but then adding it to body makes the code look prettier. Guess I shouldn't be so keen on looks ;)